# Installing Simon Listens on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, software-installation, speech-recognition

Recently I've heard about the Simon Listens package which enables you to create a speech recognition engine on Linux as well as windows. I have Linux Mind 14 - cinnamon installed on my laptop.
I wanted to install Simon Listens on this system, I downloaded the most recent version (0.4.0) from [here](http://download.kde.org/stable/simon/0.4.0/src/simon-0.4.0.tar.bz2.mirrorlist) and extracted the files. However there is no way for me to run the `build.sh` script. When I double click on it a window pops up asking me if I want to run it or run it in terminal. Regardless which option I select a terminal window flashes briefly and closes (before I can read it). I can't install it.

How can I get it to work?

**EDIT**

Here is what the `sources.list` says:

```
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ nadia main upstream import
deb-src http://packages.linuxmint.com/ nadia main upstream import #Added by software-properties
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ quantal partner
deb http://packages.medibuntu.org/ quantal free non-free

deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu quantal-getdeb apps
deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu quantal-getdeb games
```

Answer (score 2):

As you do not seem to be aware of compiling and building software, this may be really tricky for you to get running. So I'd suggest to try the ubuntu Prebuilt-Packages. This is not the most recent version available, but will eventually be updated.

So do this:

Open a Terminal( Press ALT+F2 -> Enter "xterm")

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:simon-listens/releases
sudo apt-get update
```

then try

```
sudo apt-get install simon
```

It should then be installed properly.

Please try and let us know.

**EDIT**

Sorry I can't comment thus I'm editing my answer.

Great that you still managed to run these commands :-)

Are you sure that adding the repo worked? Can you please post the output of the file /etc/apt/sources.list ? In addition please append the output of the command:

```
 apt-get update
```

I guess it did not work because the repo was designed for specific ubuntu version, but don't worry, we can still fix this. :-)

Comment: Using the ALT+F2 -> Enter "xterm" does not open a terminal and gives me an error saying that none such thing exists. (Might it be because it's Linux Mint and not Ubuntu?)

I managed to add the repository to the system but the install does not work and gives me the following error:

janiemiec20@NOS ~ $ sudo apt-get install simon
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package simon

Comment: Please see my answer below as I could not type it in the comment section.

Comment: Here is the result of sudo apt-get update:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/simon-listens/releases/ubuntu/dists/nadia/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/simon-listens/releases/ubuntu/dists/nadia/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: @Jakub
Ok I see your problem
please got the path `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and do a :
`sed 's'/nadia/quantal/g' simon-listens-releases* > tmpfile ; mv tmpfile simon-listens-releases*` make sure you match the simon-listens-releases* (it might have a different name on your system) after that repeat the steps please!

Comment: Sorry, but is this a command? : sed 's'/nadia/quantal/g' simon-listens-releases* > tmpfile ; mv tmpfile simon-listens-releases*
I'm bit confused. There is also 4 files regarding simon - two for quantal and two for nadia

Comment: Yes these are multiple commands - can you post the content of these files? you can just post them on http://pastebin.com/ so you dont have to mess with the http problems.

Comment: Here is the link to PasteBin: http://pastebin.com/aAvTijed
I type these commands and get > but nothing else happens. Don't know why.